Is it okay to plug everything into unpowered USB hub?
MBP 14" 2021. Anker hub is this thing. I have an HDMI cable plugged into it, two powered hubs, one SSD hard drive (USB-C) and USB-C power (67W).
Everything works perfectly; the hub is a tiny bit warm but not at all alarming.
Is this setup ok? Does it put the MBP's USB-C port at risk somehow? Is the data transfer somehow problematic?

Sorry..but..."ok" for what in particular? If your devices work, we have to assume its OK for those devices. Are you worried that it is warm? Electronics do that. I suppose that If it dies, you will know it was not ok.

@cmason basically the only worry here is that it's somehow bad for the computer. For instance, if that single USB-C port is going to be at greater risk than others. I've had USB-C ports go bad before on earlier MBPs (I wasn't using this setup). Thanks!

Also: any risk to data transfer? For audio interface, for instance: should I expect more glitches?

I suggest you re-word your question to include this clarification

Make sure you use the designated PD port on this hub to supply power to the devices. We have about 100 of these in classrooms and they work just fine. We've had to replace about 15 of them over the past 4 years because they've gotten zapped by bad AC power.

USB 3 can supply 4.5W (0.9A) per port for devices. In an un-powered hub, that limit rests on the 'host' USB port (i.e. the port on the computer that the hub is plugged into).
A powered hub may be able to supply each port on the hub with that total.
I'd suggest that generally, either things will work, or they won't work at all.
